# ios7 custom VC Transition: Overlap a Modal Form Sheet View

Tags: ios7, transition, uimodalpresentationstyle, uimodalpresentationformsh

i want to use the new UIVC Custom Transition API in my iPad App Project. And i despair of it -.-. what i want to do, sounds very simple at first. My "FirstViewController" (simply the names) is a normal FullScreenVC. From that VC i open a "SecondViewController"modally with the default Presentation style Form Sheet. Everything allright. The SecondViewController is a normal UiTableViewController. So from inside the SecondViewController I want to open a "ThirdViewController" modally as well with a custom transition. This ThridViewController have to overlap the SecondVC with the Form Sheet Presentation and the content of the second view controller have to be dimmed as well. But i get many problems inside the animateTransition-method in the the Transition Delegate. My best idea by now is, making a UIView Snapshot of the from View. Create a new UIView with black background and alpha 0.5 and put it as a subview inside UIView Snapshot. Then transfer the frame and the center of the fromView to the toView and add the UIViewSnappshot as a subview to the toView and send it to the back. finally adding the toView to the containerView.

But when i do this, I get two s*** problems. The First is, that the Transition don't recognize that i am using a Retina display, because i put the center of the fromView to the the toView. But the toView dont overlap the fromView, better its nit at the same postion. Its almost at the left down of the screen and not in the middle of the screen. The second problem is, that the toView content seems to be transculent. In Storyboard and in code i write "be opaque and white bgcolor". But at runtime the see the controls of the view but the bgcolor is the bgcolor of the dimmed View behind it. Why?

At the moment i think i'm a dump guy :( What in hell im doing wrong?

Thanks

Avarlon